# Loading template around Ajax links in new tabs/windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, tabs

I've had a look around stack/google and haven't quite found what I'm looking for (or the best way to do it).

Right now I have a simple static site that's using Ajax to load pages:

HTML

```
<main id="wrapper-content"></main>

<a id="nav-about" href="pages/about.html" data-link="about">
```

jQuery

```
var pageRequest = $(this).data('link');

$.ajax('pages/' + pageRequest + '.html', {
  success: function(response) {
    $('#wrapper-content').html(response);
{
```

The pages themselves contain the raw html which are loaded into the #wrapper-content div.

The initial problem I had was that when a user cmd/ctrl + clicked, or right clicked and selected "open in new tab". It would throw a 404, this has been addressed by separating the pageRequest into "data-link" and having the href point to the file (normal clicks use preventDefault and then call the Ajax function).

The problem I'm having now is that opening in a new tab or window will load the html content pages raw (without the index.html template and associated styles applied to it).

What's the best way of having new tabs/windows open with the index.html template applied around the content pages while also maintaining the Ajax call functionality where only the content is loaded into an existing page?